# Android app connected to Ajax chat

Tags: android, ajax, chat

I want to create (or at least attempt) an android app that connects to my chat on my forums for my users to be able to chat on there mobile devices. Can someone point me in the right direction for information on how to?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read [ask] to learn how to create the best question possible that will receive good answers. Your question is a little broad, can you show us some code, or tell us WHAT kind of chat / forum system you are currently using?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want Ajax because you already have html/css/js code that does this. In such a case, put your web code through [PhoneGap](https://build.phonegap.com/apps) and you have an Android app that does what you want.